# Feature Layers fail every second time the page loads, with "Error: Unable to complete operation"

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

If I create a very simple map based on the [Feature Layer On Demand](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_ondemand.html) sample, and change the URL to my own feature layer, the map consistently fails every second time:

> Error: Unable to complete operation. {code: 400, message: "Unable to
>   complete operation."
>   message: "Unable to draw graphic (null): Unable to complete operation."

If I refresh the page, the layer loads correctly, with no error messages. Refresh it again and the error shows. This applies to multiple layers on the server, not just one, so I don't believe it's related to corrupt geometry or whatever.

I vaguely remember seeing this problem a few years ago, but I can't remember the resolution. The layer is in ArcGIS Server 10.11 and I'm running the simple map via IIS on Windows 7, and accessing it via http://localhost

The only change I've made to the sample is the layer's URL, the map's starting extent, and the infoWindow contents.

[image]

Comment: How many server nodes and service instances per node are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a bug in ArcGIS Server 10.1 SP1.  identical queries will fail every other time.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/64835

you can intercept the request and modify it with a nonsense and unique parameter to work around the problem, but bumping to 10.2 (or better yet, 10.3) is a lot less trouble.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working at a client site, so it should only take about a year for the upgrade to happen ;)